# Connecting to a server service from Javascript/Mac OS X widget/Dashcode

Tags: networking, widget, dashcode

My question is fairly short: I'm trying to **open a simple TCP connection** (lets say on port 110 = POP3) **sending an command** and **getting the response** with the Javascript API inside Mac OS X widgets using Dashcode. But the problem is that I have no ideas to get this stuff working.

So have you got any ideas? I've tried on XHTTPRequest but as the name says this stuff works with HTTP protocol but I don't need this HTTP stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround: using a ruby script makes it easy to fetch those information I need. And ruby seems to be bundled with Mac OS X. The ruby script can be added in Dashcode and called via `widget.system("/usr/bin/ruby yourscript.rb", null)`.

Works for me!

Comment: If someone downloads your widget, how would they then access that ruby script?  Can you tell me how you package that?  Does that work really, or does this only work for your local development?